# Transform and Pivot in Ms-Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, transform, pivot-table

I have a table looks like:

```
Field1    Field2     Blank    Fail    Pass    Date
a         1          0        20      40      170101
a         2          1        19      99      170101
b         1          0        54      24      170101
c         3          1        24      30      170101
a         1          0        11      19      170102
b         2          0        21      266     170102
a         1          2        10      40      170103
....
```

The user then chooses the date range they want to display and I want my result to look like:

```
Field1  Field2 0101_B  0101_F  0101_P 0102_B  0102_F  0102_P 0103_B  0103_F  0103_P  
a       1      0       20      40     0       11      19     2       10      40
a       2      1       19      99
b       1      0       54      24
c       3      1       24      30      
b       2                             0       21      266
```

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: MS Access queries like any SQL query do not produce such hierarchical columns. Consider Excel pivots, SAS tables, Python pandas, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I made changes on the desired output format I want to have and made it not hierarchical columns. Is this one possible?

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. a UNION query as the source for a CROSSTAB - Parameters really should reference controls on a form.
   `PARAMETERS StartDate Long, EndDate Long;
   TRANSFORM Sum(Q.Data) AS SumOfData
   SELECT Q.Field1, Q.Field2, Q.Yr
   FROM (SELECT Field1, Field2, Blank AS Data, "B" AS Source, [Date], Mid([Date],3) & "_B" AS MonDayCat, Int(Left([Date],2)) AS Yr FROM Table1
   UNION SELECT Field1, Field2, Pass, "P", [Date], Mid([Date],3) & "_P", Int(Left([Date],2)) AS Yr FROM Table1
   UNION SELECT Field1, Field2, Fail, "F", [Date], Mid([Date],3) & "_F", Int(Left([Date],2)) AS Yr FROM Table1)  AS Q
   WHERE (((Q.Date) Between [StartDate] And [EndDate]))
   GROUP BY Q.Field1, Q.Field2, Q.Yr
   PIVOT Q.MonDayCat;`
2. three CROSSTAB queries then join the CROSSTABS
3. review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues
4. VBA procedure writing records to a 'temp' table

None of these options will allow a full year of data if there is data for every day - 2.5 months at most. Building a stable report to run perpetually based on CROSSTAB is not easy. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#ColHead.